# "Why is my Django API returning an empty list of days for routines instead of a complete nested object with exercises and notes?"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble getting a complete array of routines with each routine having multiple days, each day having multiple exercises, and all exercises having series, repetitions, cadence, and notes. The endpoint for routines is only returning its ID, name, and an empty list of days. I am using Django and Django REST Framework for this project.

Here is the code for my models, serializers, and views:

Models:

```
from django.db import models


class Ejercicio(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    repeticiones = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cadencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notas = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


class Dia(models.Model):
    dia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    enfoque = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ejercicios = models.ManyToManyField(Ejercicio)


class Rutina(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dias = models.ManyToManyField(Dia)
```

Serializers:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Ejercicio, Dia, Rutina


class EjercicioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ejercicio
        fields = ("id", "nombre", "series", "repeticiones", "cadencia", "notas")


class DiaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ejercicios = EjercicioSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Dia
        fields = ("id", "dia", "enfoque", "ejercicios")


class RutinaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dias = DiaSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Rutina
        fields = ("id", "nombre", "dias")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        dias_data = validated_data.pop("dias")
        rutina = Rutina.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for dia_data in dias_data:
            ejercicios_data = dia_data.pop("ejercicios")
            dia = Dia.objects.create(rutina=rutina, **dia_data)
            for ejercicio_data in ejercicios_data:
                Ejercicio.objects.create(dia=dia, **ejercicio_data)
        return rutina
```

Views:

```
from rest_framework import permissions, viewsets, status
from .serializers import (
    RutinaSerializer,
    DiaSerializer,
    EjercicioSerializer,
)
from .models import Rutina, Dia, Ejercicio
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.http import JsonResponse


@api_view(["GET"])
def rutina_list(request):
    rutinas = Rutina.objects.all()
    serializer = RutinaSerializer(rutinas, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


class RutinaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rutina.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RutinaSerializer


class DiaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Dia.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DiaSerializer


class EjercicioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ejercicio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EjercicioSerializer


@api_view(["GET"])
def rutinas_json(request):
    rutinas = Rutina.objects.all()
    data = []
    for rutina in rutinas:
        rutina_data = {"nombre": rutina.nombre, "dias": []}
        for dia in rutina.dias.all():
            dia_data = {"dia": dia.dia, "enfoque": dia.enfoque, "ejercicios": []}
            for ejercicio in dia.ejercicios.all():
                ejercicio_data = {
                    "nombre": ejercicio.nombre,
                    "series": ejercicio.series,
                    "repeticiones": ejercicio.repeticiones,
                    "cadencia": ejercicio.cadencia,
                    "notas": ejercicio.notas,
                }
                dia_data["ejercicios"].append(ejercicio_data)
            rutina_data["dias"].append(dia_data)
        data.append(rutina_data)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong and why I am not getting the full array of routines with all their details? Thanks in advance!

I have tried to implement a REST API endpoint to retrieve all routines, each routine with multiple days, each day with multiple exercises, and all exercises with sets, repetitions, cadence, and notes. However, the endpoint only returns the routine's Id, name, and an empty list of days.

I was expecting the endpoint to return the complete list of routines with their corresponding days, exercises, and exercise details.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have just tested your code and  `rutina_list` works as expected, returning the exact response that you want. If you are not getting any data on `days` then it means that there is no `day` assigned to a `routine`.